# how to select regex from something to something except \ (backslash)

Tags: regex

Below is the sample text. I need to select whole sentence starting from OAuth oauth_con to end without backslash. Note: Below sample text has backslash in between stack overflow prevents me from having backslash to paste.

Sample text:

```
"oauth":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"asd-asd-asd-\", oauth_nonce=\"asdasdjjasdasd\", oauth_signature=\"asdasd%sdfsdf\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"234234\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""
```

Output:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="asd-asd-asd", oauth_nonce="asdasdjjasdasd", oauth_signature="asdasd%sdfsdf", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="234234", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Comment: Sample text:

"oauth":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"asd-asd-asd-\", oauth_nonce=\"asdasdjjasdasd\", oauth_signature=\"asdasd%sdfsdf\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"234234\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""

Output: 

OAuth oauth_consumer_key="asd-asd-asd", oauth_nonce="asdasdjjasdasd", oauth_signature="asdasd%sdfsdf", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="234234", oauth_version="1.0"

Answer (score 0):

try this python code..

````
import re

test_string = """"
"oauth":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"asd-asd-asd-\", oauth_nonce=\"asdasdjjasdasd\", oauth_signature=\"asdasd%sdfsdf\",
 oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"234234\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""
"""
regex = r"(\w*[^\\])"

pattern = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
matched = pattern.findall(test_string)
print(''.join(matched))

```
Working so far...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTEEd.png
````